# How to run phone gap with xcode4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, cordova

Since moving to XCode4, I have been getting errors like:

- /VERSION: No such file or directory
- cp: /javascripts/phonegap..js: No such file or directory
- cp: /javascripts/phonegap..min.js: No such file or directory
- error: /VERSION: No such file or directory

for projects that *were* working under XCode3.

Comment: Could you post some of the specific errors you have had, then we might be able to help. I've successfully worked with phonegap and xcode 4 in the past.

Comment: thanx for reply
"shell script invocation error" this error occur in my index file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open XCodes Preferences, and navigate to Source Trees. If there is no PhoneGapLib entry there, try adding a new setting with the following values:

Setting Name: PHONEGAPLIB
Display Name: Phone Gap Lib
Path: /Users//Documents/PhoneGapLib

Note that the path should be to the location of your PhoneGapLib folder, and that it may not be in your documents folder, depending on how you installed PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about a [great web service](https://build.phonegap.com/generate) recently made available by Nitobi (makes of PG), which will automatically generate the necessary PhoneGap files you need for use in Xcode 4.

Just enter your project name, hit a button and they'll generate a zip file for you to download. This lets you set up a new project without messing with the command line.

You could set up a new project, then migrate your older project files over.

Comment: it gives these errors head: /VERSION: No such file or directory

cp: /javascripts/phonegap..js: No such file or directory

cp: /javascripts/phonegap..min.js: No such file or directory

error: /VERSION: No such file or directory

Comment: phonegap is working well with xcode3 but in 4 it gives some errors
my problem is not to create a project my problem is to solve errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you search Google for this error?

I'm a bit of a noob with PhoneGap and Xcode still, but I know there have been recent issues with PG and Xcode 4. Perhaps you're experiencing the same issues as the commenters to this post: [PhoneGap + XCode4](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/phonegap-xcode4/) (and more specifically, [here](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/phonegap-xcode4/#comment-6802)).

Comment: hmmm thanx for reply but but when i vreate my application via command line i am unable to build it
when i build it, it gives some errors.

Comment: I, myself, have not used the command line approach. So I can't offer any guidance, other than to suggest you post up some specifics regarding your error.

Also - there are several users who listed errors on both Cameron Perry's blog entry, as well as [http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/03/16/creating-a-phonegap-project-from-the-command-line-for-xcode-4/] Shazron Abdullah's blog entry. One guy even provided screencaps. Are your errors different from the ones people have shared?

Comment: this link is giving error: Shazron Abdullah’s Blog
RSS
Error 404 - Not Found

Comment: Shazron's blog link just has an extra character at the end. Lop it off, and the link works. The blog link was also part of the original Cameron Perry entry (second paragraph). Here it is: http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/03/16/creating-a-phonegap-project-from-the-command-line-for-xcode-4/